# Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in ......wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins, wordpress-shortcode

I get this error :

> Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in ......popularity-contest.php on
>   line 2574

```
function akpc_is_searcher() {
        global $akpc;
        $referrer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        $searchers = explode(' ', preg_replace("\n|\r|\r\n|\n\r", ' ', $akpc->searcher_names));
        foreach ($searchers as $searcher) {
                if (strpos($referrer['host'], $searcher) !== false) {
                        return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Can someone please help me to fix this problem?

Comment: `on line 2574` -- you better separate your file to a smaller one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning should go away if you set WP_DEBUG to false in wp_config.php. If you want to fix it, try the following:

```
function akpc_is_searcher() {
        global $akpc;
        $referrer = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        $searchers = explode(' ', preg_replace("\n|\r|\r\n|\n\r", ' ', $akpc->searcher_names));
        foreach ($searchers as $searcher) {
                if ( ! empty($searcher) && strpos($referrer['host'], $searcher) !== false) {
                        return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine! Thanks!
However, new problems encountered are: 

"Warning: preg_replace (): Unknown modifier '' in popularity-contest.php on line 2572" 

How to solve this problem?

Comment: line 2572 = $searchers = explode(' ', preg_replace("\n|\r|\r\n|\n\r", ' ', $akpc->searcher_names));

Comment: Regex patterns must be enclosed in "/". Try this: `$searchers = explode(' ', preg_replace("/\n|\r|\r\n|\n\r/", ' ', $akpc->searcher_names));`

Comment: It Looks Good, Thanks !! Really Helpful

Answer (score 11):

A bunch of PHP search functions use the terms "needle" and "haystack" as their parameter names, indicating what is sought and where to seek it.

The `strpos` function is such a function. "Empty needle" means that you have passed in a null or empty value as the needle to look for. This is like saying "search for nothing" which doesn't make sense to the function.

To fix this, check that the variable that you're passing in as the needle has an actual value. The `empty` function is a good choice for that.